# Unexpected results when passing the name of a dataframe using a list

Tags: r, dataframe, melt

There are total 17 dataframe and I have them stored in a list:

`req_dfs`

```
"data_Apr-18" "data_Apr-19" "data_Aug-18" "data_Aug-19" "data_Dec-18" "data_Feb-19" "data_Jan-19" "data_Jul-18" "data_Jul-19" "data_Jun-18" "data_Jun-19" "data_Mar-19" "data_May-18" "data_May-19" "data_Nov-18" "data_Oct-18" "data_Sep-18"
```

when I wrote a command to return the melt dataframe I got the desired results as I was passing only a single dataframe i.e.,

```
nec_col <-c("ID","Code","Name","Last Files Processed Date","Last Report Sent Date")
melt_data <- melt(`data_Apr-18`,id.vars = nec_col)
```

I get the desired outcome:

```
melt_data 

    ID      Code           Name  Last Files Processed Date  Last Report Sent Date   Variable     Value
    3498    000199~3498    H1          30/7/2019                   31/7/2019        1-Apr-19      DONE
    3343    000225~3343    H2          27/6/2018                   28/6/2018        1-Apr-19    NOTEXT
    2117    000279~2117    H3          31/7/2019                   1/8/2019         1-Apr-19    DONE
    184     001888         H4          NA                          NA               1-Apr-19    NOTEXT
    2576    0037811~2576   H5          NA                          NA               1-Apr-19    NOTEXT
    3291    003929~3291    H6          2/10/2018                   3/10/2018        1-Apr-19    NOTEXT
    3497    004434~3497    H7          30/7/2019                   31/7/2019        1-Apr-19    NOTEXT
.                       
.                       
.                       
.                       
.                       
.                       
.                       
    3497    004434~3497 H7  30/7/2019       31/7/2019       3-Apr-19    NOTEXT
```

I wrote a loop to perform melt on each and every dataframe and then perform rbind.

```
for(i in req_dfs)
{

  nec_col <-c("ID","Code","Name","Last Files Processed Date","Last Report Sent Date")

  melt_data <- melt(i,id.vars = nec_col)

  melt_final <- rbind(melt_final,melt_data)

  print(paste0("finished processing: ", i))

}
```

This loop is returning unexpected results:

```
data_Apr-18
data_Apr-19
data_Aug-18
data_Aug-19
data_Dec-18
data_Feb-19
data_Jan-19
data_Jul-18
data_Jul-19
data_Jun-18
data_Jun-19
data_Mar-19
data_May-18
data_May-19
data_Nov-18
data_Oct-18
data_Sep-18
```

I don't know how to pass the data frame to the melt function used in the loop. It could be a simple problem but for the past 3 hours I've been working on that but din't go anywhere. Any help is highly appreciated.

sample data for one dataframe data_Apr-18:

```
ID       Code           Name    Last File Processed Last report Sent   1-Apr-19 2-Apr-19    3-Apr-19
3498    000199~3498     H1           30/7/2019        31/7/2019     DONE DONE   DONE    
3343    000225~3343     H2           27/6/2018        28/6/2018 NOTEXT  NOTEXT  NOTEXT
2117    000279~2117     H3           31/7/2019        1/8/2019  NOTEXT  DONE    DONE
184     001888          H4           NA               NA    NOTEXT  NOTEXT  DONE
2576    0037811~2576    H5           NA               NA    NOTEXT  NOTEXT  DONE
3291    003929~3291     H6           2/10/2018        3/10/2018 NOTEXT  NOTEXT  NOTEXT
3497    004434~3497     H7           30/7/2019        31/7/2019 NOTEXT  DONE    NOTEXT
```

Just in case if you don't understand the sample data I'm attaching a picture 
[image: Sample Data]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you have in `req_dfs` are just names of dataframes, you can use `mget` to get them as list and then use `lapply` to loop over each and `melt` it into long format and use `rbindlist` to bind all the data in one dataframe.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(mget(req_dfs), melt, id.vars = nec_col))
```

Or if you want to use `tidyverse`, we can use `map_df`/`map_dfr` along with `gather`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(mget(req_dfs),~gather(., key, value, -nec_col))
```

Comment: OMG! that is what I was looking for, thank you so much! It worked